# Installing imageio with v3 module in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-imageio

I have been trying to import imageio.v3 module in Python3. In order to install the library, I followed two options:

`python3 -m pip install imageio`

`conda install -c conda-forge imageio`

I could see it was installed imageio-2.6.1. When importing the v3 module from import imageio.v3, I get the following error:

`"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imageio.v3'"`. Basically, it seems the v3 module is not present in my current imageio version.

How can install it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by updating conda and anaconda:

`conda update -n base conda`

`conda update -n base anaconda`

Then I reinstalled the library:

`conda install -c conda-forge imageio`